# Context value (coming from state) gets cleared while refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I have a react application which I am using context API as a state management in it. I get the a specific value from the server, assign it to a component state and then store it as the context value. But, the problem is that any time the page refreshes and reloads, the context value gets cleared as the aforementioned state is lost. Is there a way to store and keep this value even if the page reload? Is there any way other than local Storage?

I really appreciate any help.

Comment: Is there are a reason that there should be another way than local storage?

Comment: Well, I thought there might be another way. However, localStorage still works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example below is a custom hook that uses the Storage API to get and save values. It works similar to a `useState` hook but uses a `keyName` string to specify the name of the key in the storage get and set the value in.

Using this hooks allows your context provider component to get and save it's values permanently on the user's device.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

const useLocalStorage = keyName => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(() => {
    const storedValue = localStorage.getItem(keyName);
    try {
      const parsedValue = JSON.parse(storedValue);
      return parsedValue;
    } catch(error) {
      return storedValue;
    }
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const stringifiedValue = JSON.stringify(value);
    localStorage.setItem(keyName, stringifiedValue);
  }, [value]);

  return [value, setValue];
};

export default useLocalStorage
```

Example of usage:

```
import useLocalStorage from './useLocalStorage';

const Component () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useLocalStorage('user');
  ...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

When you clear a page of browser you finally clear all data related to that page(excluded localStorage and cached data).

So you need to use Local storage while you receiving data or before closing the page.

Also for some tasks you can use DB in browser to store complex data